# Indexing in for loops

Tags: r, loops, indexing

Beginner programming student here.  I'm struggling to understand indexing in for loops in R
.  I am trying to generate density curves for 3 chi-square distributions with df 4, 10, and 20.  How do I reference those 3 different distributions?  My code is below, with question marks in the indexing spots.

Thanks for the help!

Got the indexing figured out, thanks for the help.  But why is the black line in the graph not dashed like in the legend?  Isn't that specified by the lty = 2 part of the code?

```
x <- seq(-4, 45, length = 500); x  # 500 values for x ranging from -4 to 45
dist.x <- dnorm(x, 20, 5)  #returns CDF of normal distribution with mean 20 and sd 5

degf <- c(4, 10, 20)  # set  the three degrees of freedom
colors <- c("green", "red", "blue", "black")  #set up the four colors
labels <- c("df = 4", "df = 10", "df = 20", "normal")  #label the plots

plot(x, dist.x, type = "p", lty = 2, lwd = 2, xlab= "x value", ylab = "density", main = "Comparison of Normal and Chi-square Distributions")  #plot normal density curve

for (i in x){
  lines(x, dchisq(x, degf[?]), lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = colors["?"])
}

legend("topright", inset = 0.01, title = "Distributions", labels, lwd = 2,  lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2), col = colors)
```

Comment: I think you may be confounding something: you have `for (i in x) lines(x, ...)`, why reference `x` twice? To answer your question, you can do `for (ind in seq_along(x))` to iterate over the index positions, not the values themselves. From there, though, your `x`, `degf`, and `colors` are all different lengths, so I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
plot(x, dist.x, type = "p", lty = 2, ylim=c(0,0.2), lwd = 2, xlab= "x value", ylab = "density", col = colors[4],
     main = "Comparison of Normal and Chi-square Distributions")  #plot normal density curve

for (i in 1:3){
  lines(x, dchisq(x, degf[i]), lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = colors[i])
}

legend("topright", inset = 0.01, title = "Distributions", labels, lwd = 2,  lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2), col = colors)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I see now, thanks.  Why is the black line on the graph not dashed like in the legend?  Isn't the lty = 2 code supposed to give a dashed line?

Comment: @Scoonie10 It is dashed. You just don't see it since type is set to "p" instead of "l". This option controls whether you see points or line or both.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```r
x <- seq(-4, 45, length = 500); x  # 500 values for x ranging from -4 to 45
dist.x <- dnorm(x, 20, 5)  #returns CDF of normal distribution with mean 20 and sd 5

degf <- c(4, 10, 20)  # set  the three degrees of freedom
colors <- c("green", "red", "blue", "black")  #set up the four colors
labels <- c("df = 4", "df = 10", "df = 20", "normal")  #label the plots

plot(x, dist.x, type = "p", lty = 2, lwd = 2, xlab= "x value", ylab = "density", main = "Comparison of Normal and Chi-square Distributions")  #plot normal density curve

for (i in seq_along(degf)){
  lines(x, dchisq(x, degf[i]), lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = colors[i])
}

legend("topright", inset = 0.01, title = "Distributions", labels, lwd = 2,  lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2), col = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: It is usually discouraged to use `1:length(.)`, it breaks under some circumstances (though not here, it's more of a best-practices thing). It's generally better to use `seq_len` or `seq_along`.

Comment: In what case would it break? When `degf` is not a vector? Or if length is 0? Just trying to understand

Comment: `vec <- integer(0); 1:length(vec)`. Intuitively, we hope that iterating on a zero-length vector *would do nothing*, yet `1:length(vec)` here will iterate over the values `1` and `0`. Many programming mistakes are because *"this vector will never be empty"* until it is. Like I said though, highly unlikely to be a factor in this question, but it's an easy habit to get into and not think about.

Comment: Thank you, will take it into account in the future!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
x = seq(-4, 45, length = 500)

# put data in data.frame
df <- data.frame(
    ychisq4  = dchisq(x,  4),
    ychisq10 = dchisq(x, 10),
    ychisq20 = dchisq(x, 20),
    ynorm    = dnorm(x, 20, 5)
)

# create empty plot
plot(x = NA, y = NA, 
     xlim = c(-4, 45), 
     ylim = c(0, 0.2),
     xlab = "x value", 
     ylab = "density", 
     main = "Comparison of Normal and Chi-square Distributions")

# specify color and label vectors
mycolors <- c("green", "red", "blue", "black")
mylabels <- c("df = 4", "df = 10", "df = 20", "normal")
mylines <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)

# add legend
legend("topright", 
       inset = 0.01, 
       title = "Distributions", 
       legend = mylabels, 
       lwd = 2,  
       lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2), 
       col = mycolors)

# add lines to plot
for(i in 1:4) {
    lines(x, df[,i], lty = mylines[i], lwd = 2, col = mycolors[i])
}
```

[image]